# elasticsearch - how to apply lowercase before tokenize?

Tags: elasticsearch

how i can apply lowercase before tokenize?
When the vehicle is registered in the user_dictionary and searched, lowercase and upper case letters are recognized differently, resulting in different search results.
e.g. model3 => model3 (it's in user_dict) but MODEL3 => model, 3 or Model3 => model, 3
So i want to transform search term lowercase before tokenizing.

Comment: Can you explain what is the `user_dictionary`? Please provide as much information as possible so you can get better help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter lowercase in your analyzer.

```
GET _analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "filter": [
    "lowercase"
  ],
  "text": "Model"
}
```

Comment: I want to use the lowercase before applying the tokenizer. this is not what i want @rabbitbr

Comment: provide more details, please. looks like you want to use synonyms. provide examples of your query, mapping, and documents.